# Congruent Triangles.

Tags: triangles, congruences-geometry

In the diagram, CE=CF=EF, EA=BF=2AB, and PA=QB=PC=QC=PD=QD=1,
Determine BD.

[image: diagram for above picture]

Triangle APD is congruent to Triangle BQD ...   So, the areas must be equal too...   Please advise.

Comment: modular arithmetic????  Really?

Comment: sorry...clicked the wrong tag by mistake...   corrected it now...

Comment: i clicked congruences, still the tag is chosen as modular-arithmetic!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $2 \times \angle DCB = \angle DQB$ (since $C$, $D$ and $B$ belong to the same circle with center at $Q$). But $2\times \angle DCB = \angle ACB$. The latter  angle can be straightforwardly computed from $\triangle ECF$, since this triangle is equilateral. But once we know $\angle ACB$, we know $\angle DQB$, and then we can compute $BD$

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Following your approach, I get $BD={\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{19}}}}$.

Comment: I got ∠ACB = ∠DQB = 12o .   So, by cosine rule for △QBD,                     q^2 = b^2 + d^2 - 2*b*d*Cos(Q) = 1^2 + 1^2 - 2(1)(1)*Cos(12) =                2-2*Cos(12) = 0.043704.   Is this correct?   Please advise.

Comment: ∠ACB = ∠DQB = 12o . So, by cosine rule for △QBD, q^2 = b^2 + d^2 - 2*bdCos(Q) = 1^2 + 1^2 - 2(1)(1)*Cos(12) = 2-2*Cos(12) = 0.043704. Is this correct? Please advise.